# Exit the Ipad kiosk mode deployed by intune with pin

Tags: mobile-devices, microsoft-intune, ipad, mdm

I have added few Ipad device in kiosk mode with intune, As of now I am removing the policy to remove device from kiosk mode. How do I exit the kiosk mode locally from Ipad because in case there issue is with internet we wont be able to exit kiosk mode from azure portal.